# tsibble::yearmonth does not convert properly the format "2016.11" and "2016.12"

Tags: r, tsibble, yearmonth

There's a small issue with `tsibble::yearmonth`. See this list of year - months values:

```
x <- c("2016.09", "2016.10", "2016.11", "2016.12")
```

When I call `tsibble::yearmonth` (`tsibble` version 1.0.0), I obtain this:

```
tsibble::yearmonth(x)
<yearmonth[4]>
[1] "2016 Sep" "2016 Oct" "2016 Jan" "2016 Feb"
```

The function has correctly transformed September and October, but makes an error with November and December.

Workaround exists, e.g.:

```
tsibble::yearmonth(as.Date(paste0(x, ".01"), format = "%Y.%m.%d"))
<yearmonth[4]>
[1] "2016 Sep" "2016 Oct" "2016 Nov" "2016 Dec"
```

but it would be nice if `yearmonth()` recognizes the date properly.

Comment: Sounds like this might be a bug in `tsibble()` I can reproduce the same issue with two digit months on my machine

Comment: See [tsibble github issue 250](https://github.com/tidyverts/tsibble/issues/250).